# SQL equivalent for Pandas's [df.groupby(...)['col_name'].shift(1)]

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this chunk of code and I want to write it as SQL. Does anyone know how would equivalent SQL code look like?

```
lags = range(1, 5)
df = df.assign(**{
    '{}{}'.format('lag', t): df.groupby('article_id').num_views.shift(t) for t in lags
})
```

UPDATE:

I am looking for SQL standard dialect.
Here is a dataset example (partial first 10 rows):

```
  article_id section time   num_views   comments
0   abc111b     A   00:00   15            0
1   abc111b     A   01:00   36            0
2   abc111b     A   02:00   36            0
3   bbbddd222hf A   03:00   41            0
4   bbbddd222hf B   04:00   44            0
5   nnn678www   B   05:00   39            0
6   nnn678www   B   06:00   38            0
7   nnn678www   B   07:00   66            0
8   nnn678www   C   08:00   65            0
9   nnn678www   C   09:00   87            1
```

Comment: please provide a small reproducible sample data set. Also please specify which SQL dialect are you asking about...

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [LAG() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), belonging to SQL-99 ANSI standard `"windowing functions"`:

```
select
  article_id, section, time, num_views, comments,
  lag(num_views, 1, 0) over(partition by article_id order by article_id, time) as lag1,
  lag(num_views, 2, 0) over(partition by article_id order by article_id, time) as lag2,
  lag(num_views, 3, 0) over(partition by article_id order by article_id, time) as lag3,
  lag(num_views, 4, 0) over(partition by article_id order by article_id, time) as lag4
from tab;
```

[Complete and working SQLFiddle example...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6be12/2)

PS [please be aware that not all RDBMS systems implement `"windowing functions"`](http://www.sql-workbench.net/dbms_comparison.html)

Comment: Couldn't write it as fast, nice :)

Comment: @MaxU Great, thanks! Just a minor question - in case I want to create let's say 50 lags, how do I do it in a loop so I don't have to repeat the same code for each lag?

Comment: @user8436761, just generate your SQL dynamically using any programming language (for example Python).